# Magnific popup has two close x's

Tags: javascript, html, css, magnific-popup

I am integrating a front end html theme with a back-end Laravel app. Something is causing the popup modal to have two close x's. I have not been able to find out what is causing the extra x button.

The one x is loaded by added class `mfp-close` from Magnific close. Not sure how the other one is getting added in.

If I delete the "x" in the loaded html, it deletes the smaller x (which is correct). Not sure how this x is getting loaded.

[image: Close Buttons]
[image: Loaded html]

EDIT: After deleting the `mfp-close:before` css, I end up with the smaller "x", which I do not want.

[image]

Comment: it may be on the ::before pseudoelement, check if it has content: "x"; written there. Alternative way to find out if it is there, change the font-size on the before. Lemme know how this goes

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how that "x" is being loaded in the code. New to html and css.

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu how would I check the content of the pseudoelement in the css? What element is the ::before acting on?

Comment: Try to find css like `mfp-close:before ` in your css and check `content` property

Comment: Ok, I found the `mfp-close:before` class with the content "x". When I delete that line, it gets rid of the wrong "x" (the bigger one). I want to keep the bigger one (as per the template) and delete the small one.

Comment: what happens if you delete from the html the "x" == $0

Comment: Yes, as stated in the original post deleting `"x"==$0` in the loaded html deletes the smaller "x". However, this is loaded after the page via JS.

Comment: @inputchip if you want big "X" then remove `mfp-close:before` and increase font size of  '.mfp-close' in css

Comment: Thanks for all the help you guys. I realized I had loaded in the jquery.magnificpopup file when I already had jquery. I believe this was doubling the x's.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone comes across a similar problem, I solved it by loading in `magnific-popup.min.js` instead of `jquery.magnific-popup.min.js`.